# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Laravel while adding multiple values in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table Vehicle I am trying to save multiple values.

I have columns: id, vehicleno, type, make, helmet, seatbelt, cleaner, type_taxi

In this columns (make, helmet, seatbelt, cleaner, type_taxi) are set to nullable

For example 1 if the make is selected as car only seatbelt column will be filled else will be null

Example 2 if make is selected as motorcycle then only helmet column will be filled else will be null

And there can be many vehicles and for each vehicles there will be these set of questions

**Controller**

```
 public function insert( Request $request)
    {
        
        
        //accident
            $accident = new Accident();
            $accident->branch_id = $request->input('branch');
        $accident->roadname = $request->input('roadname');
        $accident->date = $request->input('dtb_yr');
        $accident->time = $request->input('appt');      
        $accident->no_of_vehicle = $request->input('noofvehicle');
        $accident->injured = $request->input('injured');
        $accident->death = $request->input('death');
        $accident->hit_and_run = $request->input('hitandrun');
        $accident->construction = $request->input('construction');
        $accident->casereg = $request->input('caseregister');
        $accident->road_maintain = $request->input('road_maintain');
        $accident->IPC_MVAct_Sections = $request->input('ipmvc');
        $accident->save();

       

        
        //vehicle
        foreach ($request->type as $key => $type)
           
        {
          $vehicle = new Vehicle();
          $vehicle->type = $type;
          $vehicle->vehicleno = $request->vehicleno;
          $vehicle->make = $request->make;
          $vehicle->helmet = $request->helmet;
          $vehicle->seatbelt = $request->seatbelt;
          $vehicle->cleaner = $request->cleaner;
          $vehicle->type_taxi = $request->type_taxi;
          $vehicle->accidents_id=$accident->id;
          $vehicle->save();
      
        }
```

dd($request->all());

```
array:25 [▼
  "_token" => "tWqfGWJVtRGmN7MBuHfARjLgliIHrDMcFejli4th"
  "branch" => "1"
  "roadname" => "Sion Panvel Special State Highway Vashi Creek Bridge to Kalamboli Junction"
  "dtb_yr" => "2021-06-15"
  "appt" => "14:26"
  "latitude" => "19.120127999999998"
  "longitude" => "72.8891392"
  "injured" => "2"
  "death" => "2"
  "noofvehicle" => "2"
  "vehicleno" => "MH054BBC4"
  "type" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Motorcycle"
  ]
  
  "construction" => "yes"
  "road_maintain" => "MMRDA"
  "caseregister" => "yes"
  "ipmvc" => "IPC 34"
  "submit" => "Submit"
]
```

Comment: can you post $request->type value

Comment: umm Sorry I didnt get you $request->type value means ?

Comment: what you get in $request->type . or just dd($request->all())

Comment: Type of vehicle

Comment: oaky.can you show the output of  dd($request->type)

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => "Motorcycle"
]

Comment: dd($request->all()); what you get.because $request->type doesnt have enough data to fill so

Comment: I have updated the question you can see

Comment: foreach ($request->type as $key => $type)
           
        {
          $vehicle = new Vehicle();
          $vehicle->type = $type;
          $vehicle->vehicleno = $request->vehicleno;
          $vehicle->make = $request->make;
          $vehicle->helmet = $request->helmet;
          $vehicle->seatbelt = $request->seatbelt;
          $vehicle->cleaner = $request->cleaner;
          $vehicle->type_taxi = $request->type_taxi;
          $vehicle->accidents_id=$accident->id;
          $vehicle->save();
      
        }

Comment: if still get eror then you to update question with full method

Comment: Array to String conversion error. In my form I have marked the name attr as [ ]

Comment: you have yo provide more detail of blade and controller method code

Comment: yeah I have updated

Comment: remove all  [] from name other than type.for example name="helmet[]" to name="helmet"

Comment: Yes then its saving the value. But what if there are multiple vehicles? will this save

Comment: you have structure blade template form properly or else  mapping data to each will be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated my controller to: Check whether the value entering is null or not and if value is not selected just set it as null

```
foreach ($request->type as $key => $type)
           
        {
          $vehicle = new Vehicle();
          $vehicle->type = $type;
          $vehicle->vehicleno = $request->vehicleno[$key];
          $vehicle->make = isset($request->make[$key]) ? $request->make[$key]:null;
          $vehicle->helmet = isset($request->helmet[$key]) ? $request->helmet[$key]:null;
          $vehicle->seatbelt = isset($request->seatbelt[$key]) ? $request->seatbelt[$key]:null;
          $vehicle->cleaner = isset($request->cleaner[$key]) ? $request->cleaner[$key]:null;
          $vehicle->type_taxi = isset($request->type_taxi[$key]) ? $request->type_taxi[$key]:null;
          $vehicle->accidents_id=$accident->id;
          $vehicle->save();
      
        }
```

Comment: Use of foreach for inserting data is wrong way, you should first prepare array of values using foreach then insert array using insert. It will save server resources and execution time.

Comment: Oh Okay Thanks wasnt aware of that will surely do that